# How to convert NVARCHAR to BIT in mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to mssql , Here I receive a parameter as "NVARCHAR" but the column datatype is BIT so I need to convert the Nvarchar data as Bit data.

Here the Nvarchar data is always either "True" or "False".

```
INSERT INTO EC_CUSTOMER_PROFILE(
                                        CP_SEND_NEWS_LETTER,
                                        CP_SEND_PARTNER_SPECIAL_OFFER,
                                        CP_CREATION_DATE,
                                        CP_CREATED_BY)

                                 VALUES(
                                        @mNewsLetter, //Nvarchar(50)
                                        @mSpecialOffer, //Nvarchar(50)
                                        GETDATE(),
                                        @mUserId)
```

Can anyone help me to fix it .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `CASE` expression, e.g.

```
CASE @mSpecialOffer WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

so...

```
INSERT INTO EC_CUSTOMER_PROFILE(
       CP_SEND_NEWS_LETTER,
       CP_SEND_PARTNER_SPECIAL_OFFER,
       CP_CREATION_DATE,
       CP_CREATED_BY)

VALUES(
       CASE @mNewsLetter WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
       CASE @mSpecialOffer WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 
       GETDATE(),
       @mUserId)
```

Comment: This will interpenetrate `NULL` values as `False` which is wrong. Null means Null not False.

Comment: Good point.  Maybe the column is not nullable.  We'll have to wait for the OP to respond.  I mean, he/she *does* say it's *always* True or False.

Comment: I read the comments ,So may I know that how should I handle the above code if I received null rather "true" or "false" ,Which will helpful for me in future @rory.ap

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it as `bit`.

The strings `True` and `False` are interpreted as you would expect.

```
INSERT INTO EC_CUSTOMER_PROFILE
            (CP_SEND_NEWS_LETTER,
             CP_SEND_PARTNER_SPECIAL_OFFER,
             CP_CREATION_DATE,
             CP_CREATED_BY)
VALUES     ( CAST(@mNewsLetter AS BIT),CAST(@mSpecialOffer AS BIT),GETDATE(),@mUserId)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO EC_CUSTOMER_PROFILE(
                                        CP_SEND_NEWS_LETTER,
                                        CP_SEND_PARTNER_SPECIAL_OFFER,
                                        CP_CREATION_DATE,
                                        CP_CREATED_BY)

                                 VALUES(
                                         CASE WHEN @mNewsLetter = 'True'  THEN 1 
                                              WHEN @mNewsLetter = 'False' THEN 0
                                         END, 
                                         CASE WHEN @mSpecialOffer = 'True'  THEN 1 
                                              WHEN @mSpecialOffer = 'False' THEN 0
                                         END,
                                        GETDATE(),
                                        @mUserId)
```